# Facebook Like button does not work on one website?

Tags: html, facebook-like

I work with hundreds of websites and only 1 isn't working. All share the same code base. I am not sure what is going on. I think it is on Facebook's end but that can't be right can it? Both use the same code, both are hosted by the same server, both send the same request out. Individually they get different responses.

The website that isn't working is sending back this response.

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,"jsmods":{"require":[["Plugin","disconnect",[],["http:\/\/mklimages.com\/"]]]}}
```

The website that is working is sending back this response.

```
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,"jsmods":{"require":[["Plugin","connect",[],["http:\/\/clweddingphotography.com\/","10150926803898226"]]]}}
```

It would appear that when the like button is clicked on the 'broken' website. The unlike response is being sent back. Both are sending the same POST requests.

Has anyone come across this before?

This is the url of the affected website: http://mklimages.com

Comment: same happens to me when i put the like button on my tumblr. did anybody find a solution to this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having exactly the same problem since the date of this post ! after seeing bugs on FB, it turned to be a bug they are trying to solve !

Comment: Can you provide a reference for that?

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me as well. I clicked Like and the popup would show for a second but would disappear. The HTTP response showed "Plugin","disconnect".

This was happening when the URL on the Like button redirected to another URL.

What I did to fix it:

1. I put the URL into the Facebook Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
2. You will see some OpenGraph warnings about missing properties. I just added a few key ones to my webpage: og:type, og:url, and og:title. Note that these three properties are marked as required on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website
3. Run the URL through the Facebook Debugger again, to clear Facebook's cache.

And Likes will work again.

Comment: Even after I made the above fix, the problem kept happening. I think it is because the Like button doesn't like URLs that redirect. I am working on changing our Like buttons to have URLs that don't redirect.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds crazy but what ended up working for me was to go to:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

and put in your problem url in the box. You should see the same issue if you click the like button here.

Then start trying to change all the other values in the other text/dropdown(width, like/recommend...)

After each change try the demo like box.  For me most did not work.
What did finally work was when I changed the font to something else.

It started working on this developer site, then I tried my real URL and it worked there as well.

It sounds crazy but it worked for me. We were having this issue for over a week on this one site and nothing worked and this was just sort of a last desperate attempt.

Comment: Testing the URL with that tool, allow me to reproduce my problem. Looks like Facebook _somehow_ doesn't like HTTP redirect. But my problem only happen on tablet device, in the desktop it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me and after a few days it just started working by itself. I guess it has to do with the facebook spam policy or something...