# Facebook - click on a like button does not increase the like count

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

After searching the internet and doing my own research on this subject I still can not find the answer to my problem, so here it is.

When I click the like button (to like my website http://openarchitecture.cz) then the like count is not being increased.

Debugging the FB javascript code on client-side (in Chrome) and examining the ajax response
send back from FB servers after the click on "Like" button, revealed that FB is instructing the Like button to be "disconnected", resulting in the behaviour described below.

The term "disconnected" is a strict FB term (in a sense of a javascript code), it means that on client-side there will be used a "plugin" that will perform certain operations leading to "inactivity" of like button. Technically, when the plugin "disconnect" is beeing recognized as part of the ajax response, there is an array of predefind actions (functions) that will be followed and called sequentially.

Now for the reproducibility of the problem.

1. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like and fill the "URL to Like" field with http://openarchitecture.cz
   url.
2. Click "Get code", then click "Ok" on the pop-up and finally click "Like" button on the right.
3. The like count should increase. Instead a pop-up shows up for (aprox.) 1 sec.
   then the popup disappears. Now I am in the same state as before I click the
   like button, i.e. like count is not increased.

I have found similar questions here on SO, but none of them seems to finally
resolve the issue.

The related questions here on SO are:
1. http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5195183/facebook-like-button-flashing-on-then-off/12958474#12958474
2.  [Facebook Like button does not work on one website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325005/facebook-like-button-does-not-work-on-one-website)

One of the suggestions was that this migth actually be a FB bug. I found a (very recently created) bug, reported in FB bug tracking system. The bug is located here: 
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/268340209965207?browse=search_512b8e0bed9724580954683

The bug has however "Low" priority an so far it does not seem to be resolved (it might even be returned as not a FB issue, I am not sure if this possibility is still open).

So for all interested in this.

1. Is this a real FB bug ?
2. How have you dealt with this ?
3. Could it be that my site is for some reason on FB spam/black/"whatever nasty" list ?

Answer (score 0):

Well. This will end up like the other posts, i.e. no lesson learned here.

[The term "page" used later in this post represents the http://openarchitecture.cz page]

I just tried today to like the page again via the FB generated like button (on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ ) and the result is now ok. So the like count gets increased after clicking the like button.

The difference that I observed when checking the request exchange to FB servers is that this time the communication has been done (by default. i.e. using the XFBML version of the like button) over iframe, not direct ajax call (as was in the past for XFBML).

I dont know what was the cause (I tried the pure iframe version of like button before) but the response going back as a result of the mentioned iframe request is now correct, ie. FB sends back response instructing javascript in client browser to use "connect" plugin not "disconnect" plug-in.

One more thing. One month ago I have created a FB profile (http://www.facebook.com/pages/Openarchitecture/125515934292877) of the page and have done some updates to this profile. So maybe FB decided that the page (being referenced from FB profile) has now earned the provilige to be "liked".

Like I said at the beginning. Problem solved, but no lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem (Like popup disappearing after a second; "Plugin","disconnect" response) was happening when the Like button URL redirected to another URL.

The fix was to add og:type, og:url, and og:title (required per https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website), then running the URL through the Facebook debugger to clear the cache (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

More at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16597060/2391566 .

Comment: I have had og:type, og:url, and og:title configured in the site already, so this does not seem to the problem in my case.